# I want to extract data from a txt file with python

Tags: python

I want to extract the initial residual values from the file attached:
http://www.filedropper.com/fixvel
But the initial residual must be referred to the "DICPCG" line and not to others (like "smoothsolver"). Then I want to store those values into a matrix that contains the values of inital residual at the same time step (on the same row) for every time-step.

Really thanks in advance

Comment: now show me some code..;)

Comment: Do you mean you want it as : `Time` value as key, and all the `initial residues`  in the list form as value for that key?

Comment: I want a matrix like this:

time       InitialResidual1       InitialResidual2       InitialResidual3     ..
0.xx1     0.00123                  0.00231                  0.0001
0.xx2     0.00043                  0.00055                   0.00087
...              ...                             ...

and so on

Comment: So, the first column of the matrix should contain time, and rest of the columns the initial residues?

Comment: What do you mean by 0.xx1, 0.xx2?

Comment: @Topcresix I have got the code for your question. Can you please clarify my doubts, so that I can post the correct answer?

Comment: I thought it display the post as you write..never mind.

I mean a matrix where on the rows there are the initial residual values of a fixed time (you can see from the file that the calculation of each loop is iterated each time-step), but only those referred to the line that in the text file starts with "DICPCG".

Since there are 4 "DICPCG" line for each time step and 3 time-steps, in this case we will have a matrix 3x4

Comment: @Topcresix There are 7 DICPCG lines for each time step. Isn't it? And do you not want to print time?

Comment: sorry man, 7 is right. No thanks, without time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```js
import re
import sys

file = open("fixVel.txt")
textfile = file.readlines()
count = -1
matrix = []
for row in textfile:
    if row.find("Time") == 0:
        count = count + 1
        matrix.append([])
    if row.find("DICPCG") == 0:
        index = row.find("Initial residual")
        index1 = row[index:].find(",")
        matrix[count].append(row[index+19:index+index1])
#print matrix
for i in matrix:
    for j in i:
        sys.stdout.write(j + " ")
    print
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it works. And let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: You're only encouraging more questions like this by attempting to answer it.

Comment: This might be a genuine requirement. Hence, helped.

Comment: THANK YOU @shruti1810, it works perfectly. You are my savior!